# AngularJS check object/array is empty

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, is-empty

I've read many questions and answers, noone has helped me. I've this function:

```
var model = {};

var mediaReproductionApp = angular.module("mediaReproductionApp",["ui.event",'ngAnimate']);

mediaReproductionApp.run(function ($http) {
    $http.get("movimenti_per_totem.json").success(function (data) {
        model.items = data;
    });
});

mediaReproductionApp.controller("MediaReproductionCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.item = model;

    $scope.playVideo = function(media) {
        return media ? "../gallery/video/" + media : null;
    }

    $scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function() {
        return Object.keys($scope.item).length == 0;
    }

    $scope.endVideo = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $http.get("php/delete_record.php").success(function () {
                $http.get("movimenti_per_totem.json").success(function (data) {
                    $scope.item.items = data;
                });
            });
            if($scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty()) {
                prelevaDati('../json/52.json', 'spot_creator', 'sc1', modello_SC, {});
                $scope.checkMediaData();
            }
        },1800);
    }

    $scope.checkMediaData = function() {
        $http.get("movimenti_per_totem.json").success(function (data) {
            $scope.item.items = data;
        });
        if($scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty()) {
            $timeout(function(){$scope.checkMediaData();},2000);
        }
    }

    $scope.checkMediaData();
});
```

This is my JSON file when it is not empty:

```
[ {"media":"zafferano_VP8.webm"}, {"media":"amaretti_VP8.webm"}, {"media":"passata_VP8.webm"}]
```

It never return true when it is empty. I've tried also:

```
$scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function() {
    return $scope.item.length == 0;
}

$scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function() {
    return $scope.item == {};
}

$scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function() {
    return angular.isUndefined($scope.item) || $scope.item === null;
}

$scope.reproductionCodeIsEmpty = function() {
    return angular.isUndefined($scope.item.items) || $scope.item.items === null;
}
```

Nothing works... can u tell me why?
Thank you!

Comment: We don't know what `model` is or where you use this code. Provide  a [mcve]. Note that `return $scope.item == {};` would never work due to different object references

Comment: I'v edited my question! With more infos

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: `console.log(data)` and check what is in there when the json is empty

Answer (score 1):

*After you added to your question:*

You define model as: `model.items = data;`

So, you empty model is: `model = { items: [] }`.

That's why it isn't empty. You need to test for `model.items` being empty.

---

If you need a tested way to tell that the object is empty, I'd recommend `lodash.isEmpty()`. You can use it for "any Array-like values such as arguments objects, arrays, buffers, strings, or jQuery-like collections".

https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#isEmpty

Since I don't know what your `model` is, this would cover the most possible data types.

```
_.isEmpty(null);
// => true

_.isEmpty(true);
// => true

_.isEmpty(1);
// => true

_.isEmpty([1, 2, 3]);
// => false

_.isEmpty({ 'a': 1 });
// => false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if object/array is empty, I use:

```
angular.equals({}, yourObject);
angular.equals([], yourArray);
```